# Understanding -f in bash if statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following `bash` code and it works perfectly as I change the value of '`ca`':

```sh
ca=4

if  [ -f $(($(($ca > 2)) && $(($ca < 1)))) ] ; then 
    echo  "I can't reach here"
else
    if  [ -f  $(($(($ca == 4)) && ($((4 == $ca))))) ] ; then 
         echo  "It is 4"
    else
         echo  "Else works wonders"
    fi
fi
```

but if I remove "`-f`" from within the `if`-statement, it outputs everything wrong. As far as I have searched, `-f` is for files but I don't understand how does it work in the above case. Also, any suggestions on alternative ways of writing those complex expressions within `if`-statements in bash would also be helpful.

Note: The code above looks weird, because it isn't handwritten and is converted from JS using a *transpiler* that I am working on. The original JS code is below:

```
let ca = 4;
if (ca > 2 && ca<1) {
  console.log("I can't reach here");
} else if(ca == 4 && (4 == ca)){
    console.log("It is 4")
}else {
  console.log("Else works wonders");
}
```

**Further Edit/Solution:**

Now I am able to correctly transpile the above and other expressions using 
[*Diego Torres Milano*'s recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56501775/6136214).

I have put up an example input and output of the transpiler below so that anyone facing similar issues might get some ideas.

Input JS/TS:

```
let ca = 3;
if (ca > 2 && ca<4) {
  console.log("3!!");
} else if(ca == 4 && (4 == ca)){
    console.log("It is 4")
}else {
  console.log("Else works wonders");
}

var cb = true
let cc :any = false //"any" is used for calming the TS compiler

if(cb==cc){
    console.log("I will never be logged")
}else{
    console.log("Expect me!")
}

if(!cc){
    console.log("Negation?")
}
```

Output Bash:

```
ca=3

if  ((  $(($(($ca > 2)) && $(($ca < 4)))) )) ; then 
  echo  "3!!"
else
  if  ((  $(($(($ca == 4)) && ($((4 == $ca))))) )) ; then 
    echo  "It is 4"
  else
    echo  "Else works wonders"
  fi
fi

cb=1
cc=0

if  ((  $(($cb == $cc)) )) ; then 
  echo  "I will never be logged"
else
 echo  "Expect me!"
fi

if  ((   ! $cc )) ; then 
 echo  "Negation?"
fi
```

Comment: -f is not a flag to 'if', it is an option to 'test' (the [ after if is 'test' - see help test). And it checks for the presence of a file, so whatever math you're doing after looks completely bogus.

Comment: `if` just takes a command as its argument. `[` is not `if` syntax, it's a command (the command also called `test`; you can also call `[` or `test` on its own, without using `if` at all).

Comment: BTW, please don't tag for multiple shells. If you want a bash answer, tag only bash. If you want a zsh answer, tag only zsh. Don't tag both at the same time; they're different shells, and not mutually compatible.

Comment: ...unless you're trying to target multiple specific shells and you have a portability issue (but their may be a tag for that - [tag:posix], perhaps).

Comment: Just to be clear: the transpiler you're using is not translating the tests correctly. The tests will only work as they should if you happen to be in a directory that contains a file named "1" but not one named "0". That part of the transpiler needs some serious work...

Comment: `sh` is the tag for POSIX shell, which would probably make for a better target than `bash`.

Comment: There's an inherent semantic problem here: JS variables have types and comparisons do "the right thing" based on that; in shell, variables are untyped (basically, everything's a string), and you have to use different syntax for integer vs string comparison. Some examples of the difference: for strings, "05" and "5" are different (and "05" will be considered "less" because  it comes first in lexicographic order). Similarly, for strings, "19" is less than "2"; for integers, it's the other way. Thus, to know what shell code to emit, you must know the "type" of the variables.

Comment: For integer comparison, you can use `((a<b))`, `$((a<b))` (and then compare the result to "0" or "1"), or `[ "$a" -lt "$b" ]`. For string comparison, use `[ "$a" \< "$b" ]` instead. For floating-point number comparison, you have to use an external tool like `bc`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes you are right, at the moment, type inference is limited, I build up a symbol table to infer the right types from variables and expressions. But I cannot do the same for functions due to JS allowing multiple return types. The other issue being not able to emulate `===` JS operator. The other option I am considering is generating awk scripts(which have some concept of types) as awk is likely available in most UNIX systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arithmetic evaluation

```
ca=4
if (( ca > 2 && ca < 1 ))
then
   ...
```

What you are evaluating with `[` without the `-f` is if STRING is not empty.

Comment: Thank you, the above suggestion also allowed me to solve a whole host of other issues like unary expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Some notes on the JS code:

```
let ca = 4;
if (ca > 2 && ca<1) {
  console.log("I can't reach here");
} else if(ca == 4 && (4 == ca)){
    console.log("It is 4")
}else {
  console.log("Else works wonders");
}
```

Taking these in order:

1. The code:  `let ca = 4` translates to `ca=4`.
2. And...

   ```
   if (ca > 2 && ca<1) {
     console.log("I can't reach here");
   } else
   ```

   ...since it's impossible for `ca` to be greater than `2` *and* less
   than `1`, this code is needless, and should be omitted.  If it were
   needed, (and some program or function named `console.log` existed),
   it would be translated like so:

   ```
   if [ $ca -gt 2 && $ca -lt 1 ]; then
     console.log "I can't reach here"
   else
   ```
3. This code:

   ```
   if(ca == 4 && (4 == ca)){
       console.log("It is 4")
   }else {
     console.log("Else works wonders");
   }
   ```

   ...has a redundant test of `ca`, which should be omitted.  It can be
   translated to:

   ```
   if [ $ca = 4 ] ; then
       console.log "It is 4"
   else
       console.log "Else works wonders"
   fi
   ```

---

Taken as a whole, we get:

```
ca=4
if [ $ca -gt 2 && $ca -lt 1 ]; then
  console.log "I can't reach here"
else
    if [ $ca = 4 ] ; then
        console.log "It is 4"
    else
        console.log "Else works wonders"
    fi
fi
```

...or with the needless code omitted:

```
ca=4
if [ $ca = 4 ] ; then
    console.log "It is 4"
else
    console.log "Else works wonders"
fi
```

Comment: The transpiler I am working on doesn't optimize the AST yet, The redundant tests are to validate the correctness of the output when same expression is inside the parenthesis. What I am having trouble is with converting those parenthesis to bash/zsh format, getting rid of them is not an option as they will be required as expressions get complex.

Comment: The current title of the Q is *"Understanding -f in bash if statement"*.  My answer is a practical demonstration that the `-f` (or `test -f`) is not relevant for variable comparison logic.  If that title does not adequately reflect the question, please consider retitling it.  If it's a transpiler Q., it would be better to actually show some transpiler code.